# Como colocar td como link.

Tags: php, tabela-html, link

Bom dia, pessoal!

Gostaria de colocar o conteúdo de uma `<td>` como um link para que o usuário consiga acessar a imagem que está em uma pasta no servidor.

Essa é a :

```
//Montando o corpo da tabela
  $table .= '<tbody >';
  while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($qry)){
    $table .= '<tr>';
    $table .= '<td>'.$r['ID'].'</td>';
       $table .= '<td>'.$r['OQUE'].'</td>';
       $table .= '<td>'.$r['NOME'].'</td>';
       $table .= '<td>'.$r['IDENTIFIANT'].'</td>';
       $table .= '<td>'.$r['PREDIO'].'</td>';
       $table .= '<td>'.$r['POSTO'].'</td>';
       $table .= '<td>'.$r['INICIO'].'</td>';
       $table .= '<td>'.$r['DATA'].'</td>';
       $table .= '<td>'.$r['MES'].'</td>';
       $table .= '<td>'.$r['HORA'].'</td>';
       $table .= '<td>'.$r['ANO'].'</td>';
       $table .= '<td>'.$r['LOCALLESAO'].'</td>';
       $table .= '<td>'.$r['TIPOLESAO'].'</td>';
       $table .= '<td>'.$r['LADOLESAO'].'</td>';
       $table .= '<td>'.$r['FONTELESAO'].'</td>';
       $table .= '<td>'.$r['ACIDENTE'].'</td>';
       $table .= '<td>'.$r['ATENDIMENTO'].'</td>';
       $table .= '<td>'.$r['HOSPITAL'].'</td>';
       $table .= '<td>'.$r['CONCEQUENCIA'].'</td>';
       $table .= '<td>'.$r['FALHA'].'</td>';
       $table .= '<td>'.$r['DESCRICAO'].'</td>';
       $table .= '<td>'.$r['IMAGEM'].'</td>'; //É SÓ ESSA AQUI

      $table .= '</form></td>';
```

Se puderem me ajudar, eu agradeço. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Considerando que o `IMAGEM` é um link para a imagem, você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
$table .= '<td><a href='.$r['IMAGEM'].'>'.$r['IMAGEM'].'</a></td>';
```

Caso contrário seria necessário substituir o conteúdo do `href` pelo link que você gostaria que o usuário fosse direcionado.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente. Só vou esperar o tempo estipulado pelo StackOverflow para marcar como resposta certa. Obrigada!

Answer (score 0):

Faça assim:

```
$table .= '<td><a href="caminho-da-imagem-na-pasta">'.$r['IMAGEM'].'</a></td>'; //É SÓ ESSA AQUI
```